# Spring Session Redis Auto DeSerializer un-unsed keys

Tags: redis, spring-session

we are using spring-session-data-redis starter, and meet one problem during this process.

We have two application A and B, and want to share same redis between A and B.

the problem is as below:

1. We call API in application A to add one User object to current Session:(url: http://localhost:9001/test) logic as below.

> @RequestMapping("/test")
>
> @ResponseBody
>
> public User addUser(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
>
> User user = new User("TEST", 10);
>
> HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
>
> session.setAttribute("SESSION_USER", user);
>
> return user;
>
> }

2. Then call API in application B to visit another service ( this service is very simple, return a String) (url: http://localhost:9002/test) logic as below.

> @RequestMapping("/test")
>
> public String test() {
>
> return "OK";
>
> }

3. But application B will return error when visit url: http://localhost:9002/test, and application B does not have this class(com.du.demo.demo1.controller.model.User) under classpath..

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Could not read JSON: Could not resolve type id 'com.du.demo.demo1.controller.model.User' into a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: no such class found at [Source: [B@703e37; line: 1, column: 11]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'com.du.demo.demo1.controller.model.User' into a subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: no such class found at [Source: [B@703e37; line: 1, column: 11]

4. My question is that whether there are some configuration to skip this? Exception will only throw when we use this object? Just want to stop the automatically deserialize process...

Comment: resolved, we override exists Serializer class in RedisOperations method.

Comment: public byte[] serialize(Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
        try {
            return serializer.convert(object);
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            return handleException(ex);
        }
    }

Comment: private byte[] handleException(final Exception ex) {
        if (null != ex && null != ex.getCause() && null != ex.getCause().getCause()
                && (ex.getCause().getCause() instanceof ClassNotFoundException)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            throw new SerializationException("Cannot serialize", ex);
        }
    }